# Excel: macro to auto-format time for example 20130808191057 would be formated to 19:10

Tags: excel, datetime, format, vba

I’m exporting a report that includes End Time of when jobs have completed but the time gets exported in the following format 20130808191057 (yyyymmddhhmmss).

I tried using the date and time auto formatting from excel but none seems to work.

I need a macro or a VBA script that would take a range of cells lets say K4:K86 
and format the times which are shown as 20130808191057 and format it into 19:10

If possible I would also like to be able to add my initial at the end of the time to show that the work was double checked, so in the end the format would end up like this 19:10 IT

Ultimately I need a range of cells K4:K86 whos datetime is shown as **20130808191057**
to be formatted as  **19:10 IT**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a formatting issue.  With data in A1, use the formula:

**=TIME(MID(A1,9,2),MID(A1,11,2),RIGHT(A1,2))**  and format the cell with the formula in a time format.

If you need a macro to transform the data into times, the select the cells to be changed and run:

```
Sub TimeCreator()
    Dim r As Range, t As String
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        r.Clear
        r.Value = TimeSerial(Mid(t, 9, 2), Mid(t, 11, 2), Right(t, 2))
        r.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm  ""IT"""
    Next
End Sub
```

To avoid processing empty cells, test for them:

```
Sub TimeCreator()
    Dim r As Range, t As String
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            t = r.Text
            r.Clear
            r.Value = TimeSerial(Mid(t, 9, 2), Mid(t, 11, 2), Right(t, 2))
            r.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm  ""IT"""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks works great. One thing though.  When I’m selecting the cells to format some blank cells get selected in the process, and if i run the macro i get an error. is there a way to run the macro on a selection which might include a blank cell and have it work? Otherwise I would have to do multiple selections which could be in the hundreds. The data is in one column so if I could select just the entire column would be even better. Thanks again